# How do I prevent root access from all TTYs

Tags: security, root, tty, restricted-access

I am trying to secure root access on my Ubuntu servers (running 14.04 desktop and 16.04 server). I would like to disable root access on all TTYs except TTY1. I know this can be done by editing /etc/securetty, and commenting out all devices except TTY1, but I am unsure about the `Local X displays`. Should I comment those out as well? what about the `UART serial ports`, `Serial Mux devices`, `Chase serial card`, `Cyclades serial cards`, etc, etc.

There are so many devices so I am unsure as to how to deal with securing this file. Can you lead me in the correct direction as to what devices I should disable for a working system but root can only log in from TTY1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're spending your effort on trifles. If Bad Guy can attach a terminal, Bad Guy can boot from his USB.

But, since `man securetty` says `securetty - file which lists terminals from which root can log in` it implies that you could comment out all but `TTY1`. Commenting out (or not) lines for hardware you don't have makes no difference.

Since, if you mess with `/etc/securetty`, you can end up locked out of your system, you must test carefully. If you have `batch` or `at` set up and running you could do by setting up a `root` batch job to do::

```
cp /etc/securetty /etc/securetty.original
cp /tmp/modified.securetty /etc/securetty
sleep 20m
cp /etc/securetty.original /etc/securetty
```

And do your testing in the next 20 minutes, after which, the original (working) `/etc/securetty` is restored.

Comment: I would probably be testing it in a VM before I deploy it, but I if I do comment out all the devices except tty1, I should not have any other side effects, correct?

Comment: I have no idea. That's what testing is for.